# How can I add parameter to POST request from h:commandLink?

Tags: jsf, post, jsf-2, parameters, navigation

I have two JSF pages: A.xhtml and B.xhml.

A.xhtml:

```
<html ...>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <h:commandLink value="To B page" action="#{bean.goToB}">
          <f:param name="aURL" value="A.xhtml"/>
      </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

with bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    public String goToB(){
      //some logic... 
      return "B.xhtml"?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

and B.xhtml:

```
<html ...>
  <h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="aURL"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <h:link value="To A page" outcome="#{aURL}"/>    <----- this link is disabled

  </h:body>
</html>
```

Marked above link is inactive, disabled. It is a simple label. Why can not I from the B.xhtml return to the A.xhtml? Where is the mistake?

Comment: `name="aURL"` doesn't bind the parameter to anything. It just names it. You want `param.aURL`, which picks the named parameter from the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I make so mistake in name of JSF page (I write page.xhtml.xhtml).

I don't have to remove xhtml extension at outcome in `link`, i don't have to remove `f:metadata` and i don't have to use `#{param.aURL}` (i can use `#{aURL}`)

Thank's everyone for help (especially for César Loachamin and kolossus).

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is because you are not passing a valid outcome, so first try putting some valid outcome the name of the page without the xhtml extension and you will see it render as link.

So first the name of the page that return an action method or the outcome in the `h:link` must not have the xhtml extension so there is a Page1.xhtml the action is Page1. Remove the xhtml extension.

Second when you use the `f:param` in the command link it will be a parameter in the request so if you redirect to another page using the `faces-redirect` it value will be lost because the browser will make a new request, so remove faces-redirect.

And finally to get the value send from the `f:param` use the predefined bean `param` so:

```
<h:link value="To A page" outcome="#{param.aURL}"/>
```

And remove the `f:metadata`